# Materialize select dropdown not passing value to controller in Ruby

Tags: ruby, html-select, materialize

I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
  <form method="POST" action="/results">
    <input type="text" id="track" class="validate" name="inicio">
    <label class="active" for="track">Nro Inicial de Tracking:</label>

</div>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select name="sucu">
      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
      <option value="5472">Clorinda</option>
      <option value="5266">Formosa</option>
    </select>
    <label>Seleccionar Sucursal</label>
  </div>
  <button style="text-align:center;"class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
</form>
```

And in my controller I'm grabbing the tracking number and `sucu` value like this:

```
inicio = params[:inicio].to_i
@sucursal = params[:sucu].to_i
```

Now, for some reason, the controller is getting the `inicio` param, which is a number I input, but is not getting the value of the dropdown, instead of getting one of the two values `5266` or `5472`, I receive a `0`.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? Do you have any scripts that may affect the selected option before submitting the form? Could you share the complete code for your controller's action?

Comment: i have no other select input, the controller is just that, the rest of the controller is not affecting the behavior, the error is not in the controller, it must be in the view somehow, because its passing a null value (0)

Comment: I can confirm that is passing null, because if i remove the to_int on the param, it doesnt return a thing...so any ideas why the selector is giving null?

Comment: I can't spot any error in your code (i even tested it and got no error) so i guess that the problem may be somewhere else, not in the code your sharing. Can you share your complete view code?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you remove the first option (`<option value="" disabled selected></option>`)?

Comment: yeap, same error, are you recreating this with materialize? because i believe is something related to that...

Comment: yes, its passing nil, i tested by adding to the controller:
    
     `if params[:sucu].nil?`
      `@sucursal = "nil"`
    `end`

and printing out sucursal on the view, and im getting that `nil` string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141689/discussion-between-gerry-and-frenciaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the error is with Materialize, which seems to ignore the `select` value. So, in order to get the value, you could add a hidden `input` that will act as a placeholder for the value that is selected, and then update its value when your `select` box changes.

```
<form method="POST" action="/results">
 <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input type="text" id="track" class="validate" name="inicio">
    <label class="active" for="track">Nro Inicial de Tracking:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <label>Seleccionar Sucursal</label>
    <select id="sucu_select">
      <option value="" disabled selected></option>
      <option value="5472">Clorinda</option>
      <option value="5266">Formosa</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="sucu" id="sucu" />
  </div>
  <button style="text-align:center;"class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
    $('#sucu_select').on('change', function() {
      $('#sucu').val($('#sucu_select').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

I added an `id` (`id="sucu_select"`) to the `select` box and created the hidden `input` that will store (and post) the `sucu` value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sucu" id="sucu" />
```

Then i added jQuery to update the hidden value:

```
$('#sucu_select').on('change', function() {
  $('#sucu').val($('#sucu_select').val());
});
```

May not fix the problem itself, but now you can get the selected value through `params`.

Comment: this worked!! thank you very much!! Now, do you know why materialize could behave like this? It has something related to jquey itself?

Comment: Good! I'm glad it worked. I don't know why Materialize behaves like this, i haven't looked into their code (and probably won't in a near future) but i'm pretty sure that it's something with their implementation rather than jQuery itself.